# использование массивов в тестах в Postman

Tags: тестирование, postman

отправляю запрос на покупку товара. В теле передается например

```
    "products":[
            {
                "id":"1",
                "quantity":3
            },
            {
                "id":"5",
                "quantity":2
            }
        ]
```

В теле ответа:

```
"order": {
            "id": "",
            "user": {
                "id": ,
                "email": ""
            },
            "products": [
                {
                    "product": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "",
                        "price": 100,
                        "iamgeUrl": ""
                    },
                    "quantity": 3
                },
                {
                    "product": {
                        "id": "5",
                        "description": "",
                        "name": "",
                        "price": 500,
                        "iamgeUrl": ""
                    },
                    "quantity": 2
                }
            ],
            "totalQuantity": 5,
            "status": "paid",
            "totalSum": 1170
        }
```

Задача: с помощью Postman протестировать, что скидка (10% при более 3 единиц товара) считается верно. Проблема в том, что товар может быть 1, а может быть больше и тоже с количеством. Как написать эту логику, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Answer (score 0):

Задача: с помощью Postman протестировать, что скидка (10% при более 3 единиц товара) считается верно. Проблема в том, что товар может быть 1, а может быть больше и тоже с количеством. Как написать эту логику, пожалуйста, подскажите?

Это различные тесты. Вы должны составить тест (Postman request) для случая без скидок и для случая со скидкой и сравнить результаты.

Comment: Не понял вашу мысль. Мне ведь просто нужно проверить, что при кол-ве товаров больше трех добавляется скидка, так? Зачем два теста?
Пока получается
pm.test("The amount is calculated correctly", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    let sum = 0;
    jsonData.transaction.order.products.forEach(item => {
        sum += item.quantity * item.product.price;
    });
    if (jsonData.transaction.order.totalQuantity >= 3) {
        if (jsonData.transaction.order.totalSum === sum * 0.9) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}); Как завернуть это в т

Comment: Идея проста, я не знаю ваших форматов. Чтобы узнать что меняется нужно сохранять результаты тестов чисто эмпирический подход. А так про100 посмотрев на небо и не поймешь что что-то меняется

Comment: так товары и их кол во может быть разное. я пытаюсь написать универсальную функцию. то есть мы знаем товары, кол-во и цены, спарсив это из ответа и знаем, что скидка должна быть 10% при >3 , я пытаюсь написать функцию, которая бы вернула true или false. вот только не знаю синтаксис

Comment: Никогода не старайтесь что либо унифицировать не имея при этом не унифицированную вешь. Рефакторинг или оптимизация производится только если есть рабочий код для сравнения результатов. В вашем же случае напишите в ручную несколько примеров и потом постарайтесь выделить общий знаменатель. Переход всегда должен быть от простого к сложному.